# ARM7 assembly shifting a number with a signed integer

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-shift, arm7

I have been trying to shift my number with the formula m*2^-n  by using Logical Shift Right (LSR). for m = 8 and n=-2 I should be getting 8(2)^-2 ie; 2, but I get 0 for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first negate `R1` before you can do `ASR`.  Shift values are unsigned, a negative shift value is interpreted as a very large positive shift, leading to a result of zero.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but how do I negate my R1 value?

Comment: @WebDeveloper Use the `RSB` instruction: `rsb r1, r1, #0`.

Comment: that still seems to give me 0? I have placed this piece of code right above MOV R0, R0, ASR R1

Comment: Hmm I am still not sure how to nullify R1, the RSB didn't seem to work

Comment: @WebDeveloper Can you please show a [mcve] including your updated code?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cmr33X2diWfFtmh9sNGXORz3AhjBPq8q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @WebDeveloper I'm not going to look at external links.  [Edit] your question and put the material in there.

Comment: Ok doing that now

Comment: updated the machine code

Comment: @WebDeveloper Your code is not a [mcve] because I cannot compile the C code as is.  Please post something I can compile as is.

Comment: alright I have given my exact C and ARM7 machine code now - please note that I am compiling and running on raspberry pi

Comment: @WebDeveloper With the code you provided, the final code in your question works as expected.  Make sure you have actually recompiled the final code.

Comment: yes it does thank you so much!! I have another question - if I am making an isequal  program will the machine code stay the same for both R0,R1 as unsigned integers and R0,R1 as signed integers? or will I have to change something

Comment: Not sure what an `isequal` program is supposed to be, but likely the code will differ.

Comment: I have posted this question, could you please have a quick look at it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375161/same-arm7-assembly-code-for-two-unsigned-integers-program-and-two-signed-integer