# Same ARM7 assembly code for two unsigned integers program and two signed integers program

Tags: assembly, arm, arm7

I used the same code for two programs minu and mins which both have to find the smallest integer of the two inputs. minu takes in two 8 bit unsigned integers wheras mins takes in two 16 bit signed integers.

program 1 (minu):

```
uint8_t a = 5
uint8_t b = 10
//result should equal 5
```

program 2 (mins)

```
int16_t = -10
int16_t = 10
//result should be -10
```

---

ARM7 machine code:
program 1:

```
minu:
  CMP R0,R1
  BGE end
  BX LR 
end: 
  MOV R0,R1
  BX LR
```

program2:

```
mins: 
  CMP R0,R1 
  BGE end
  BX LR
end:
  MOV R0,R1
  BX LR
```

Comment: Your code is again incomplete.  Make sure to present a [mcve].

Comment: There's also no question here.  You've shown some code, but not said anything about whether it works or not when you test it, or asked any questions *about* it.  Erik and I just kind of inferred the obvious question of "is this correct?" but I only posted an answer because it got a bit too large for a comment.

Comment: Your edit removed all the code for both versions!  That makes zero sense and makes the question much worse in its current form; now it doesn't show which instructions you actually used.  And it's still not asking a question; there aren't any sentences ending with a question mark here.

Answer (score 2):

You have used signed comparison operations, and on 32-bit registers.

This is ok, if the caller used the proper load instructions to fetch and convert the 8-bit/16-bit data from memory into registers that are being compared (or else otherwise managed the conversion from 8-bit/16-bit to 32-bit).

For the unsigned 8-bit code you would need to use `LDRB` and for signed 16-bit, `LDRSH`.

In the unsigned case, using `LDRB` will convert 8-bit unsigned data loaded from memory to 32-bit by zero extension — the top 24 bits of the register get zero, and the lower order 8 bits the value from memory.  This final value in the register after `LDRB` is always going to be >= 0 whether interpreted as signed or unsigned in 32-bits, since the sign bit in the registers will be zeros.  It is up to you whether to consider the 32-bit value signed or unsigned, because we know that it will always be positive (non-negative) so in a sense it doesn't matter.  The C language would say it is `int` which is a signed data type, because it gravitates toward `int` and `int` can easily hold any value from a signed byte and/or an unsigned byte.

In the signed case, using `LDRSH` will convert 16-bit signed data loaded from memory to 32-bit signed value in the register.  It does this by propagating the sign bit from bit 15 of the 16-bit memory halfword into all the bits of the upper half of the register.  It is important in this case to consider the 32-bit register with the signed data type, since we may have negative or positive values.

---

When you have 32-bit values in memory, they can neither be sign extended nor zero extended to fit in a 32-bit register, as all the bits are already specified from memory.  As a result, for unsigned you would *have to use unsigned >= conditions — meaning the branch instruction would have to change to `BHS` (branch higher or same)*, whereas for signed you would *have to use signed >= conditions (`BGE`)*.<sup>1</sup>

Because your code is said to use smaller data types (smaller than 32-bits: 8-bit unsigned, and 16-bit signed) you can get away with using signed comparison for both types — provided the values are properly and accordingly extended to 32-bits into the registers.

If the values were loaded from memory into registers with an incorrect sign/zero extension, you would have to fix that with other instructions before using the comparison operations.  On x86, however, you can compare just the lower 8-bits or just the lower 16-bits of the registers with each other due to its partial register feature.  On the x86 processor using smaller size compares, the above comments about the full 32-bit value made above<sup>1</sup> would also apply.

Answer (score 1):

That will happen to work if your caller follows the standard calling convention and passes args zero-extended or sign-extended to 32-bit according to their signedness.  Unlike `uint32_t`, all `uint8_t` values can be represented as non-negative signed `int` (32-bit), so signed comparison like BGE will give the correct result.

i.e. using a function that treats them both as 32-bit signed `int` works; that's the point of this calling convention rule, because ARM doesn't have a `cmp` instruction that could compare only the low 8 or 16 bits of input registers.

That's not what compilers do, though, they use `cmp` / `movlo   r0, r1` vs. `movlt   r0, r1` for unsigned LOwer vs. signed LEss-than.  (MOV if the predicate is true, otherwise it runs as a NOP).

See it on the [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMVxxdpgOqUIETMQE6T5%2BZZj2uQzVtQT5YZHRsbY1dQ2ZZYNdwT1FfaUAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma25iwCSECCz72CYaAILrm9uYewcKBPiCAHQIF1e3N17BBAAHAB9Ag7FjBLwQf6CEFgpikHYwoGgnYRGZ7ADsVhuOzxO2ImAIiwYOxe6BAIAhDAgCPR%2Bxxt0xABEfj8AVwAGyo6kKCAc7nwxEC1HorGM/EEokksmvSnU2mkelrRkmFlsv4MZLAELoHYAL0wqgI0IBcJ2TBmaol%2BMJxOIpKYDLZ6pu7MEZKNJpF8Kt2J%2BkrtMqdKpdzI4c1onAArLw/BwtKRUJw3NZrGSFktHuseKQCJoI3MANYgNZrd5rLmAgCcnOrmOrGkkdbiUY4kjjBaTnF4ChAGjzBbmcFgSDQLHidGi5Eo48n9BitRYpTMA5otAI0T7EAiXYiwVqAE9OLnx2xBAB5Bi0Y8J3hYFiGYDiO%2BkfCEyoAN0wfdfRoqXibievAAi0Xa0HgETEEeHhYF2BDEHgLDAXMVAGMACgAGp4JgADuF7xIwwEyIIIhiOwUgkfIShqF2uhmPoT4oGmlj6JBfaQHMqDxG0v4ALQXmsOx8Y%2BxAsMJADqYi0L2LQVG0LgMO4niNKWnKkIEEyFMUWRJCkAjDH4azqdk%2BkMN02nTLYcmVAIHRDCpmTGdZrRVGMFm9CUAydIZaneXUHlTCUcwKJmyx6AhmArDwkYxp2r7Jhw1wAEoALJopCji0AoOxmO8ZiAjsEDXAoShFDeiK4IQJB7GYlaIh4E5TsQtVrGYMy8Pmd4zMWpblmskj1nWnKApinJcPWmL6JwHakPGiaJb2/aDt1pAjogKCoE1C4zhAc7NSAS6fpifFbE%2BpQaHE66bsQ267q%2B%2B7MMQt6nlt54EFeN5dg%2BT4vom77yXg36/om/7IIB0UgYIYGvhBUEwRgKyJghSEoXw6FYTh%2BGEfGub8KRojiJR%2BPUSo6ivrorZMaYljWGxEQcRAXE8ak/GCcJoniXxUm0DJLmA84ECuL5dUaUpgU6WsCR6W0ItS6ZbQS30UvlLZ7RjL51b82r9njAUnmlv59SOX4WsvJ0SsxGsIVhRReaEpDsUcLGc1dolKXpcAyDIDspT5UVEEMF4qgYhAqa06xOxVUQLU5g1W3ztErVcB1K1aD1pAlmWFZlrned59N7bxQtPa2MtXXp07Zi8MhXAaAO828ItaeFqQ363akICSEAA) compiler explorer.